# Is there a record of the Frankist talmud disputation?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, shabbetai-tzvi

In 1757 followers of the apostate Jew, [Jacob Frank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Frank) engaged in a disputation with Rabbinic Jews regarding the talmud. I would like to know if there is any record of the contents of that disputation.

Comment: How do you know such a disputation happened?

Comment: http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0005_0_05259.html

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6279-frank-jacob-and-the-frankists

Comment: thanks @SethJ it looks like that second link has the answer - לתולדות התנועה הפראנקית I will post that as an answer.

Comment: this book might have additional information http://www.askives.com/the-mixed-multitude-amazon.html

Answer (score 6):

[לתולדות התנועה הפראנקית](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/45492) written by Majer Bałaban records some of the contents of this disputation.

Answer (score 0):

On the 26th on Tammuz

Frankists Vanquished (1759)

The Frankist sect was created by Jacob Frank, who claimed to be the reincarnation of the false Messiah Shabbetai Zvi. In the mid-1700’s, he sought to create a new religion that would incorporate both Judaism and Christianity, leading to the formation of the Frankist sect, centered in Poland.

In 5519 (1759), the bishop of Lvov arranged for a debate between the Frankists and three prominent Jewish leaders: R. Israel of Mezhibuzh (the Baal Shem Tov), R. Chaim Rappaport, and R. Yitzchak Dovber Margulies. The four-day debate ended with a resounding victory for the rabbis, and the date was instituted as a day of rejoicing, celebrating the successful halt of the Frankists’ evil influence. (Hatamim, pp. 550, 558. See also Igros Kodesh, vol. 19, p. 81) (https://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tdate=7/6/2021)

Comment: The OP is seeking sources about the subjects debated. How does this answer that question?

Answer (score 0):

This may be too general of an answer for you but here is the overview and why there probably would not be any accurate account of what was said : It wasn’t an ideological debate with  each side trying to argue of behalf of their cause. It was just a standard middle age story of Jewish renegades going to the church and telling them that the Talmud says…so therefore…with an ensuing forced debate afterwards.

The Frankists had already denied all belief in Gemora at the time. They claimed to only believe in the Zohar as the authoritative Jewish book of law. They  told  that to  the Catholic Bishop of Kamenetz-Podolsk. They also made the claim  to  him  that the Zohar accepts  the Trinity Doctrine  with the messiah being one of the three (but of course neglected to say that he and they had a very different belief as to who the messiah was…)  The bishop forced the Jewish community (represented by the seven  rabbis and nineteen layleaders the church choose) to engage in debate with the Frankists.

The Frankists came with nine arguments ostensibly against the Gemara  but in reality they were all very similar to the standard  Xtian  Tanach based arguments  that the Xtians believe vindicates their religion. The ones I  recall revolved around how to translate certain Hebrew words and the exact wording of a posuk. The Franists were apparently basing their arguments on Xtian translations of Tanach as opposed to the original Loshon Kodosh version.  That put the Rabbis in a bind because they couldn’t speak too strongly against Xtianity  when participating in a forced debate under the auspices of the bishop. They therefore answered  in general terms.

As expected the ruling was in favor of the Frankists. The bishop ordered the Jewish community  to pay a fine to the Frankists , and to burn all copies of the Gemara  in Podolia.

With that background  other than the main points there probably wasn’t anything of major ideological substance being said at that debate anyway. Therefore probably  no one felt the need to record  the actual debate in detail. Reb Dov Ber from Buchilov in the sefer Divrei Bina writes his account of what he saw transpire but as far as what I saw quoted (I never saw his actual sefer)   did not include what was actually said at the debate.